# Converting py::array to Eigen::Ref from C++

Tags: python, c++, numpy, eigen, pybind11

I'm using pybind for an interface to a program that uses Eigen internally to access a 2D array, and should be able to receive a Numpy array from python.

I have a function like this:

```
void A::f(const Eigen::Ref< Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 3, Eigen::RowMajor> >&)
// bound using
m.def("f", &A::f);
```

From Python it is called like this:

```
# arr is a Nx3 array
a.f(arr)
# or, when arr is not of float64 type:
a.f(np.asarray(arr, dtype=np.float64))
```

if I'm correct, the latter call creates a temporary Numpy array, that persists in memory during the call to `f()`. And the Eigen::Ref<> will reference that memory, without additional copy.

---

But now the function instead has multiple such arguments, and there are multiple similar functions. So I instead have a `View` class, which holds pointers to the data, and `f` receives a `View` object:

```
struct View {
    const Eigen::Vector3d* ptr;
    std::size_t rows;

    View(const Eigen::Ref< Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 3, Eigen::RowMajor> >& arr) {
        assert(arr.rowStride()*sizeof(double) == sizeof(Eigen::Vector3d));
        ptr = reinterpret_cast<const Eigen::Vector3d*>(arr.data());
        rows = arr.rows();
    }
};
A::f(const View&);

// bound using
py::class_<View>(m, "View")
    .def(py::init<const Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 3, Eigen::RowMajor>>&>());

py::class_<A>(m, "A")
    .def("f", &A::f);
```

This works fine if used from Python like this:

```
# arr is a Nx3 array
a.f(arr)
# arr is not of float64 type
arr_copy = np.asarray(arr, dtype=np.float64))

view = View(arr_copy)
a.f(view)
```

However, it seems this usage does not work:

```
# arr is a Nx3 array
a.f(arr)
view = View(np.asarray(arr, dtype=np.float64)))
a.f(view)
```

...because the copy of `arr` no longer exists when `a.f()` is called.

---

One way to solve it seems to be to create a `View` subclass, that contains the `py::array` object from pybind11 (= ref-counted handle to the Python object):

```
struct PyView : View {
    py::array arr_;

    PyView(const py::array& arr) :
        arr_(arr) // ensure that the Python object will persist during lifetime of PyView
    {
        View::set_array( ?? );
    }
}
// where there is a function
// View::set_array(const Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 3, Eigen::RowMajor>>&)
```

Is there an API in Pybind11 to get a Eigen::Ref (or the Eigen::Map that would be passed to it), from an `py::array`, the way it would normally do automatically?

Or alternately, is there a more elegant way of handling this? Such that ideally, there is only one place in the code that needs to take care of the details of the memory layout and set the `View::ptr`, `View::rows` values correctly.